# How to have a for loop create multiple eventListeners in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

everyone.

I am trying to manipulate DOM so whenever the user clicks on the categories, I want their background to change to a pinkish color. I tried to add an eventListener to only the first of those categories (whose class is '.select'), and it worked fine. Then I tried to write code for a for loop that can add eventListeners for all of the options, and it didn't work. Also when I run the code for the case in which only the first option gets impacted, its font color is still not changing. How do I fix these issues? Here are my code segments:

```
<div class="categorybox">
                <ul>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Love</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Health</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Gratitude</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Sleep</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Spiritual</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Money</a></li>
                    <li class="select"><a href="#">Blessing</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

```
const category = document.querySelector(".select");

category.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  category.style.background = "#eb3352";
  category.style.opacity = "0.7";
  category.style.color = "#fcfafa";
});
```

In the case above, my font color doesn't change to the color I specified (#fcfafa).

Then I tried running the code below.

```
const categories = document.querySelectorAll(".select");

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
  categories[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    categories[i].style.background = "#eb3352";
    categories[i].style.opacity = "0.7";
    categories[i].style.color = "#fcfafa";
}});
```

In the case above, none of the selected list items changed.

Comment: Change `var i` to `let i` and it will work. See the linked question for details.

Comment: You can also use `e.target` to get the element that was clicked.

Comment: You have syntax error on the end of your script. Change ```}});``` to ```});}```
Inside listener use ```e.currentTarget``` instead ```categories[i]```

Answer (score 0):

The code you used with `document.querySelectorAll` does not work for two reasons:

- Your parentheses and braces are misplaced.
- You should use `let` instead of `var` so that `i` is scoped to the loop block. With `var`, `i` just ends up as `categories.length` which is the value seen inside the event handler functions.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    categories[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        categories[i].style.background = "#eb3352";
        categories[i].style.opacity = "0.7";
        categories[i].style.color = "#fcfafa";
    });
}
```

However, consider using event delegation instead. This way, you can just attach the event listener to the parent, then check if the click was on one of the children. `event.target` can be used to access the element that was clicked.

```js
document.querySelector('.categorybox > ul').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const li = e.target.closest('li.select');
  if (li) {
    e.preventDefault();
    li.style.background = "#eb3352";
    li.style.opacity = "0.7";
    li.style.color = "#fcfafa";
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="categorybox">
  <ul>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Love</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Health</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Beauty</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Gratitude</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Sleep</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Spiritual</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Happiness</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Money</a></li>
    <li class="select"><a href="#">Blessing</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```